# Компиляция в linux

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, компиляция, c++, linux

Как скомпилировать следующую программу в linux с учетом библиотек postgres

```
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libc.h>

int     main() {
    PGconn          *conn;
    PGresult        *res;
    int             rec_count;
    int             row;
    int             col;
    FILE            *stream;

    conn = PQconnectdb("hostaddr=192.168.143.92 port=5432 connect_timeout=5 dbname=NexentaSearch user=DKOI
     password=21111991");
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
        puts("Не удается подключиться к базе данных");
        exit(0);
    }

    res = PQexec(conn, "select path from paths order by id");

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
        printf("Мы не получили данные");
        exit(0);
    }

    rec_count = PQntuples(res);

    printf("Мы получили %d записей.\n", rec_count);
    puts("==========================");

    stream=fopen("usr/local/paths.txt", "w");
    for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
        for (col=0; col<1; col++) {
            fprintf(stream, "%s\n", PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
        }
        puts("");
    }

    puts("==========================");
    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

Попытка компиляции с помощью команды `gcc -c readwritepaths.cpp` привела к ошибке

> gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Comment: @ivan31, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: g++ доставьте

Comment: а как с помощью g++ компилировать?

Comment: @ivan31, когда gcc "видит" расширение файла .cpp, он решает, что это программа на c++ и вызывает соответствующие модули компилятора. 

Компилировать g++ - аналогично gcc

    g++ readwritepaths.cpp

Кстати, Вам наверное нужно будет указать (через ключи -l), какие библиотеки Postgres полключать и возможно, в каком каталоге их искать (через -L)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g++ -I/usr/include my_program.cpp -o my_program_bin -L/usr/lib/ -lpostres
```

Что-то типа этого, только нужно указать инклюды и библиотеки postgreSQL.

Comment: `-lpq` же, нет?

Comment: @Re1aps, /usr/include и /usr/lib можно не задавать (это каталоги "по умолчанию").

Comment: Неужели? я намекал на - "только нужно указать инклюды и библиотеки".

Comment: @Re1aps что означает my_program_bin?

Comment: g++ - компилятор
-I/usr/include/postres - путь к инклюдам постгреса. Это тебе самому нужно посмотреть где они лежат, предположительно я написал.
my_program.cpp - файл с программой.
-o - создать бинарник(исполняемый файл)
my_program_bin - имя бинарника, тобишь того файла который ты будешь запускать.
-L/usr/lib/postgres - путь к либам постгреса, опять же тебе нужно уточнить это у себя
-lpostgres - название используемых библиотек. Когда все это сделаешь в терминале перейди в папку с бинарником и сделай следующее ./my_program_bin

Answer (score 0):

Вы хоть посмотрите, что делаете. Вы пытаетесь программу на С++ (поскольку включены iostream и пр.) и имеющую расширение .cpp скомпилировать с помощью gcc - компилятора языка Си. Что делать: либо удалить все плюшные инклюды (при беглом осмотре, текст в остальном совершенно сишный) и изменить расширение файла на .c, либо компилировать g++.